# Make OneDrive stop syncing when there are too many folders

Tags: windows, onedrive

How can I change the folders to be synced in OneDrive, without opening OneDrive?

All I want to do is make OneDrive stop syncing all folders, except for one. But I can't do it because the app is too busy syncing... the folders I want it to stop syncing.

Here's the situation. I have hundreds of thousands (maybe over a million) of files in OneDrive. I am now coming from a fresh install of Windows 11. OneDrive by default is configured to sync all folders, which means that as soon as the app opens and I am logged in, it starts "processing" hundreds of thousands of files that exist in the cloud but not in my laptop. This long operation basically never finishes, even with the "cloud files" enabled (i.e. the files exist in my laptop only as download-as-you-go shortcuts). I am on a new, ultrabook-level laptop with 64 GB of RAM.

If I try to stop syncing any folder, it says it is not possible because some local files are not in the cloud; which is false, since the only direction of data flow happening here is cloud to laptop.

I'm wondering if there is some manual registry change, or something similar, that I could use as a hack of sorts into OneDrive's settings.

Answer (score 0):

And do you open your OneDrive on other devices? If so, you can simply transfer this one folder you need to another cloud and then to your laptop.

Of course, it isn't what you've been searching for, but sometimes we overcomplicate stuff.